# state={selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)}

Tags: react-native

I am using "flatList" and there was multiple items in it and when on Click each item app show me their detail in next page. For this purpose I use id method and also get help react-native doc. In this I saw this code in ts form can anyone tell me how to write this code into js because  I am using react-native and I am using js

```
state={selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the typings

```js
state = { selected: new Map() }
```